# Excel Pivot Table Date Sort

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am unsure how to phrase this question and I have been searching for a day and cannot find a solution. I am working with Excel 2013 and pivot tables. I have a spreadsheet of all help desk calls (I am new to the help desk as a supervisor) and the dates when each ticket was created. What I want to do, is develop a simple graph showing the number of tickets created by year using a Pivot Table.

I have a single column labeled Date Created. I want to be able to create a Pivot Table or actually a chart that sums the total number of tickets created per year. I know I can achieve this with a lot of manual work, formatting, copy, pasting etc. It seems to me a Pivot Table can do this for me with a lot less steps. I am even willing to be it is fairly simple to accomplish, I am just overlooking something. I would appreciate any help.

Here is a sample of data in the column I am looking at.
5/31/2012
5/31/2012
5/31/2012
6/15/2012
6/15/2012
6/25/2012
6/25/2012
6/26/2012
7/6/2012
7/9/2012
1/7/2013
1/10/2013
1/14/2013
1/16/2013
1/23/2013
1/23/2013
1/29/2013
2/11/2013
2/11/2013
2/20/2013
2/22/2013
2/22/2013
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/22/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
12/23/2014
1/12/2015
1/12/2015
1/12/2015
1/12/2015
1/12/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015
1/13/2015

Comment: have you checked out some other posts? Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720031/count-number-of-times-a-date-occurs-and-make-a-graph-out-of-it

Comment: I did look at the post and while similar is not what I am looking for. I need to be able to total 2012, 2013, 2014, and 2015. Not list them out separately. The Count If does not work as I have already tried that. It either does not like formula I enter in the Pivot Table or when done outside the pivot table and in a cell the formula does not just pick out the year.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you.

Transpose the data so it will look like this:
[image]

After that is complete, highlight all the data and go to:

> Insert -> Pivot Chart

If it asks you again to highlight the data, do so.

When you get to the pivot table. Takes the `Dates` criteria and add it to **BOTH** Values and Axis (Categories).

You will then see a chart.  A small pivot table will list out all of the dates, right click a random date and choose `Group`.

[image]

Highlight only the `Year` criteria and it will show you what you are looking for.

Result:
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so very much. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help!