# Count and visualize number of times a date occurs for each contacts and make a graph out of it

Tags: excel, csv, date, data-visualization

I have a .csv document containing a list of 40 000+ contacts for which I have the list of the moment they were contacted (by email) in a date; hour format (i.e 2017-01-17 12:02:00)

**Example**

```
contact 1 2018-09-15 14:02:00 2017-01-17 12:02:00
contact 2 2016-02-17 02:03:00 2016-03-17 04:32:00 2017-11-14 08:42:00
```

What I'm trying to do is to count the number of time a contact has been contacted in a given day or week. Ideally, be able to know

- Max number of time a contact has been contacted per day/week during the selected period
- Average number of time a contact has been contacted per day/week during the selected period

A bit like this: [Count number of times a date occurs and make a graph out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720031/count-number-of-times-a-date-occurs-and-make-a-graph-out-of-it)

Except I have not just one list of dates but more or less 40 000

Thank you all!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a minute to read that article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to know what is the actual purpose of StackOverflow and what is actually a good question. Here we see what you want, we understand your challenge. Now, we can help you if you try it by yourself first. Show us some effort and piece of codes where you get struggled and we will help you. You have to understand that we won't help a non developer to get a job done without paying a developer, right?

Comment: I tried exactly what's in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720031/count-number-of-times-a-date-occurs-and-make-a-graph-out-of-it

It "kind of" worked but only for on contact... I need to scale the formula for my entire list of contacts

Comment: Show what you got and what is your output looks like. What is the code you tried... I mean it smell bad after my comment you did not add any code line...

Answer (score 0):

Just for this part :

> to count the number of time a contact has been contacted in a given day or week

I suggest to save the file as .xlsx > then select the top header of the data > Goto 'Data' > 'Filter' . Then apply your desired numbers/contacts/date/date-range .

So to get :

> • Max number of time a contact has been contacted per day/week during the selected period

select the desired contacts + date-range . Then copy the data (date column only) to another sheet.. select all then press F11 to get instant graph.

and for this :

> • Average number of time a contact has been contacted per day/week during the selected period

select the desired contacts + date-range . Then copy the data (date column only) to another sheet.. and put your formulas there (average for per day and per week needs different formula/filter).

Hope it helps. (:

Comment: @LouisChaussé  mind sharing your solution ? (for the benefit of future readers..)